# Match all strings where substring doesn't belong to a certain group of words

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of files that all end with '_', three numbers and '.csv'.
I want to delete all those that don't end in '_005.csv', '_007.csv', '_008.csv' and '_111.csv'.

I tried to delete all those that match `^.*_(?!005|007|008|111)\.csv$` but it didn't work. How do I do it?

Comment: @anubhava I am on Windows, working with R on Rstudio. I am trying to use the file.remove function using a pattern

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a POSIX system you can do:

```
ls -1 | grep -vE "_(00[578]|111)\.csv$" | xargs rm
```

Or you can use negative lookahead, as you've attempted in your question. One thing to keep in mind is that the characters inside negative lookahead `(?!   )` are not part of the match, so you have to specify the match as well. In other words your regex would be something like this:

```
_(?!(00[578]|111))[0-9]{3}\.csv$
```

To break it down consider this regex first:

```
_[0-9]{3}\.csv$
```

This will match all files ending with `_`, three digits and `.csv`.

Now we add negative lookahead to exclude our specific cases. So, you insert `(?!(00[578]|111))` after the `_` and end up with the above.

Again, on a POSIX system you can do:

```
ls -1 | grep -P "_(?!(00[578]|111))[0-9]{3}\.csv$" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! However the regex `^.*_(?!(00[578]|111))[0-9]{3}\.csv$` only works when I try it on [here](https://regex101.com). I am using R with Rstudio: when I try to remove all files using `file.remove(list.files(pattern = "^.*_(?!(00[578]|111))[0-9]{3}\.csv$"))` it says that '\.' is an unrecognized escape. If I try to remove the backslash (since before 'csv' there is always a dot anyways) it tells me `invalid 'pattern' regular expression`

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. You need to enable PCRE in Rstudio. I quote: _"By default R uses POSIX extended regular expressions. You can switch to PCRE regular expressions using PERL = TRUE for base or by wrapping patterns with perl() for stringr."_ Ref: [Basic Regular Expressions in R Cheat Sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: I also believe in R you need to escape the \ character. So instead of removing it, try adding another \. So, you should have `\\.csv$`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
^.*_(?:(?!005))(?:(?!007))(?:(?!008))(?:(?!111))\.csv$
```

?

Comment: I tried it but it doens't work. Check for yourself on https://regex101.com using 'foo_009.csv'

Answer (score 0):

This regex **wont** capture files '_005.csv', '007.csv', '008.csv' and '_111.csv'.

**Regex**: `_(?:(00)|(11)|([1-9][02-9]))(?(1)[^578])(?(2)[^1])(?(3)\d)\.csv$`

**Details**:

`(?:)` Non-capturing group

`(00)|(11)|([1-9][02-9])` Alternatives

`|` or

`[]` Match a single character present in the list

`[^]` Match a single character not present in the list

`(?(n))` If `Group n` then

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HqCf9A/3)